# How To allow unexperienced users to use my Puppet module

Tags: puppet

I am developing opensouce project with a huge pile of dependencies, and I find Puppet a perfect tool for my requirements.

However, my target audience is not necessarily experienced with Puppet. To the point they may not be even know how web servers work. So I would like to ask the user to “run this in terminal” for the simplest case, but if the user also wants to configure some parts of my software, he would have to learn puppet. And educating them Puppet defeats the “servers for dummies” purpose of my project.

Basically, dare I say, I need Unity from the deployment world.

The thing I came up with, is to use ‘json’ as a backend for Puppet, and then write some GUI tool that would generate/modify that json using JSON Schema. Of couse, this thing will be optional and experient Puppet usets could still just use my module as is.

The questiond is, am I doing it right? Is there a solution for my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These users are what: developers, ops, etc.?

Comment: @MattSchuchard these are client game developers.

Comment: Then offering them the ability to use Puppet via access to your Puppet CI (with job launch permissions) that executes Puppet at the end would be familiar and comfortable for them and safe and easy for you. What tool do you use for your Puppet Ci to streamline your testing and code deployments?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I simply use git repository for configuration, and then clone it in the right folder. I see streamline problem as different task on _how deliver configuration_, rather on _how edit configuration_ I am trying to cover here.

Comment: Oh: your question says you want people to use your module and not edit it. Typically the permissions set for developers at companies is they are allowed to execute your Puppet catalog but not modify the code and data. They may as well just learn basic Puppet in that case.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem: Puppet DSL is hard to learn. So it makes use of my project harder when I want it to be easy. `apt-get install` easy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158077/discussion-between-desertkun-and-matt-schuchard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Hieradata**](https://puppet.com/docs/hiera/3.3/puppet.html) to give the ability to users to configure some parts for your "Software". you can put your hiera configuration in a git repository or build a tool to edit & update this hiera configuration.

There is some tools that you can use in order to make more easier for your users like [**Foreman**](https://www.theforeman.org/) and [**Puppetboard**](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppetboard)

But I think it's mandatory for your users to have a basic knowledge of Puppet so they can debug or manipulate the software.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Essentially, your first paragraph is what I meant by `json` as [hieradata] backend. I just hoped that off chance someone already made that kind of tool.

Comment: for now you can use a SCM like git or svn, Or you can build or wait for a tool like that.

Answer (score 1):

These are some things that you can use.
Have a look at these:-

https://puphpet.com/

https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppetboard